# Using MaxLength attribute to specify NVARCHAR(MAX)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, razor-pages

Using code-first data annotations, is it possible to use the `[MaxLength()]` attribute to specify a string column should be `NVARCHAR(MAX)`?

It doesn't appear to support this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use the [MaxLength()] attribute at all on your property, it'll create a column as NVARCHAR(MAX) by default I believe

Comment: I could've sworn I read somewhere that it was something like 120.

Comment: I suppose (just thinking) it kind of makes sense that not applying an attribute will result in the maximum size of column possible in the underlying database, because the entity class doesn't 'know' anything about the underlying implementation - the maximum possible string column size might differ between MSSQL, MySQL, Oracle etc

Comment: It looks like this is true. Better be sure to set the length for all your string columns if you don't need `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write like this [MaxLength(-1)] ?,